# How to add dependency for two build types with one configuration?

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle

My app consists of 2 flavors and 3 build types:

```
productFlavors {
    free
    paid
}

buildTypes {
    debug
    beta
    release
}
```

I can simply add a dependency for all variants, specific flavor or build type:

```
dependencies {
    implementation "some-dependency"
    freeImplementation "some-dependency"
    betaImplementation "some-dependency"
}
```

To add a dependency for a specific variant, I can do do this:

```
configurations {
    freeDebugImplementation
}

dependencies {
    freeDebugImplementation "some-dependency"
}
```

---

**But what I want is to combine several flavors/build types/variants.** Something along the lines of:

```
configurations {
    debugBetaImplementation
}

dependencies {
    debugBetaImplementation "some-dependency"
}
```

which should be equivalent to:

```
dependencies {
    debugImplementation "some-dependency"
    betaImplementation "some-dependency"
}
```

Is there a way to achieve this?